# RestRequest timing out after 30 seconds

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I'm trying to extract data from a 3rd party API using the following C# code that uses the RestSharp library (v. 110.2.0).  My problem is that the call to the client.Execute() method
often ends with this result:

> Request failed with status code RequestTimeout

However, it seems to fail after about 30 seconds.  Note that in my code, I've set both the RestClientOptions.MaxTimeout and RestRequest.Timeout to 10 minutes.  Why is it aborting after only 30 seconds?  Is there any property I can use to have it wait longer?

```
var options = new RestClientOptions(uri)
{
    ThrowOnAnyError = false,
    MaxTimeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds
};

using (RestClient client = new(options))
{
    RestRequest request = new(_reader.Uri, Method.Post);
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("HttpVerb", "POST");
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
    request.AddHeader("ResourceUri", $"/api/{TransactionType}");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
    request.Timeout = (int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds;

    RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(response.Content);
    else
        throw response.ErrorException;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how the timeout works with RestSharp, but you may want to use the `ExecuteAsync()` method and `await` that instead of using a blocking call: https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#making-a-call. You could also try to set the timeout to `-1`, which should mean that it's infinite.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I implemented it as an async call and it still times out after 30 seconds.  Also tried -1 but same thing happens.

Comment: The issue can be on server side. For nginx it could be exactly 30 sec. See https://serverfault.com/questions/777749/how-to-disable-timeout-for-nginx

Comment: I think @AndreyGurenkov is right as RestSharp is setting the `HttpClient` timeout to the value from `MaxTimeouts` in milliseconds, and use the request `Timeout` property for the cancellation token source. There's no 30 seconds timeout defined in RestSharp.